# What is an easy way to write the results of an SQL query to a Web Forms Response in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, json

I need an easy way to write the results of an SQL query (`SQLDataReader` via `sqlcommand.ExecuteReader()`) to a Web Forms Response (i.e., some string written to `Response.Write(string)`) and in a format that is easy to read in PHP. I was thinking of creating a JSON Object, converting that to a string, and writing that JSON string to a response, but I can't find an easy way to do that in Web Forms.

I'm thinking something like:

```
{ "tableColumn1": "value",
"tableColumn2": "value"}
```

but I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do this using an SqlDataReader.

The ultimate goal is to make often-evolving table data in a .NET environment easily accessible to read in a Linux environment using PHP.

Comment: Why you don't go directly on db from your PHP app?

Comment: I wish we could, but my boss doesn't want a connection between our internal network and our public-facing website... which is more secure, I guess.

Comment: If you have to take data from the internal network and expose it on public one you are force to have some kind of connection between them. Perhaps your boss prefer an HTTP connection over direct db access, which is a questionable preference.

Comment: @MatteoSp, yeah, I agree, but that's what he has done, and I'm unlikely to be changing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class myClass
{
    public int myColumn { get; set; }
    public string myColumn2 { get; set; }
}

public string MySqlMethod()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable;";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var listToConvert = new List<myClass>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var toAdd = new myClass();
                toAdd.myColumn = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("myColumn"));
                toAdd.myColumn2 = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("myColumn2"));
                listToConvert.Add(toAdd);
            }
            return GenerateJson(listToConvert);
        }
    }

public static string GenerateJson<T>(List<T> obj)
    {
        var returnString = "[";
        var listCounter = 0;
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            returnString += "{";
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                returnString += "\"" + prop.Name + "\":" + "\"" + prop.GetValue(item, null) + "\"";
                counter++;
                if (counter != props.Count())
                    returnString += ",";
            }
            returnString += "}";
            listCounter++;
            if (listCounter != obj.Count())
                returnString += ",";

        }
        returnString += "]";
        return returnString;
    }
```

This is completely 'doable' in WebForms, this isn't specific to MVC.
The upkeep on this is pretty simple, a minor change to the custom class and, some new dr.GetWhatever when the table changes.

If you want a more dynamic solution, I would look into the Entity Framework, if possible.  Then you can just create partial classes that compliment the auto-generated ones that EF makes.  The upkeep is almost null at that point.

Comment: As much as I would love to do that (I'm a huge fan of MVC), I'm not sure I can expect my coworkers to maintain the class's changes as the table in the database changes.

Comment: You could just have the SqlDataReader store a record into a list of strings, then adjust the above method to handle List<string>, should be rather straight forward.

Comment: Apparently, my coworkers aren't as bad I thought they were. They were actually creating a class for that table, so your answer has inspired me well enough to make things work out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Page_Load event, you need to clear the response and then handle it manually, using below codes :

```
string response = string.Format("[ \"tableColumn1\": \"{0}\",\"tableColumn2\":\"{2}\"]", value1, value2).Replace('[', '{').Replace(']', '}');
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(response );
Response.End();
```

Comment: While this doesn't perfectly answer my question, it helps a bit, so thanks!